# C++ 'no instance of overload function' why am I getting this error?

Tags: c++, getline

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>

using namespace std;


int main()

{ 
    string name, choice;
    int age;

    cout << "Enter a name: ";
    //Getline will allow to take an entire line as an input and not a char 
   getline(cin, name);
   cout << "Enter choice of meal: ";
   getline(cin, choice);
   cout << "Enter age: ";
   **getline(cin, age);**

   cout << "My name is " << name << endl;



  return 0;

}
```

This is my code
The problem is in the bold line can anyone please tell me why the error is coming and the solution for it?

Comment: `#include <string>` is missing

Comment: Please add the error. Also, make sure your code is a [mcve] and could be compiled, i.e. don't mess up the syntax using "**" markers!

Answer (score 1):

The answer why you code doesn't work is that `getline()` online allows you to read strings but not integers. Interestingly, there are no facilitien provided for reading other types in the C++ IOStreams library. This is so interesting, because line-based and delimiter-based stream processing, and in particular mixing them, is always a source for problems. Being able to use the approach you tried would be much easier and safer, I would say.

There's a simple solution (untested):

```
template<typename value_type>
istream&
getline(std::istream& in, value_type& val)
{
    std::string line;
    if (!getline(in, line)) {
        return in;
    }
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    if (!(iss >> val)) {
        in.setf(std::ios::failbit);
    }
    return in;
}
```

Basically, it reads a line and then converts it to the according target type in two steps.

Comment: Wouldn't the failure of `in >> val` itself set `failbit` on `in`? (note -- typo in code `iin`)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin `in` and `iin` are separate streams in this code. `iin` is not a typo. Personally, I would have named it `iss` instead.

Answer (score 0):

When you get errors like this, it's time to look up the signature of the function you use. E.g. look at this documentation [std::getline](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline). All of the overloads only accept a (template version of)  std::basic_string&, there is no version accepting an int. So you need to look for another way of going from a string input an to an integer value. In this case you might want to check the documentation of the [<string>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/string) header.